# javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: jsp, servlets, maven, jstl

I am seeing the below errors in my jsp page -

```
javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext cannot be resolved to a type
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException cannot be resolved to a type
```

I have seen a post on this and tried few things that were suggested. BalusC provided a great input - JSTL1.2 and Standard.jar must not be used together. I did this and it fixed the issue for sometime - but it is reappearing. I am not sure if I have any more jar collisions. I have defined all the jars as dependencies in Maven. The below are the dependencies that I have specified pom.xml -

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.38</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: I am unable to answer my question now. The issue is now solved. Instead of JSTL1.2 jar as dependency, I added JSTL-API and JSTL-IMPL jars as specified in this link http://www.andygibson.net/blog/quickbyte/jstl-missing-from-maven-repositories

Comment: In case someone gets this error in eclipse, check project properties -> Project Facets -> Dynamic Web Module -> Runtimes

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You will need to import in your project the JSP APIs, which are not included in servlet-api

In my project, the solution is:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064269/the-method-getjspapplicationcontextservletcontext-is-undefined-for-the-type-js

Seems like your solution raises a different error .[ The accepted answer ] .

Answer (score 32):

The solution that worked for me, is given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15782094/453673). Go to project properties > Targeted runtimes > Select the checkbox for a runtime (Apache Tomcat 7 in my case).
That's all. Just build the project now and everything will be fine.

Comment: Works for me too on Eclipse/Luna.  I already had the servlet-api included which deals with the Java dependencies, just needed tell Eclipse which Runtime to check against and all those annoying JSP "errors" disappeared!

Comment: This solution works for me.

Comment: It works for Marse 1.1 as well

Comment: This worked for on Mac OS X Eclipse and all these errors disappeared

Comment: Worked like a charm!
Can you explain why eclipse has this behavior?
I think, there are some dependencies that we don't put in the POM, but servlet container (Tomcat in this case) provides them instead, and we can put these in our pom under <scope> as provided.
I'm i right or wrong? i'm just started to learn java

Answer (score 5):

Assuming this is the pom for a web application...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

A number of these dependencies should be set as *provided* as they are provisioned by the container. You should not bundle these with your application. See [Maven dependency scopes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope). Failure to do this may result in undefined behaviour.

Exactly which dependencies are provided depends on the container.

Answer (score 0):

"The solution that worked for me, is given in this answer. Go to project properties > Targeted runtimes > Select the checkbox for a runtime (Apache Tomcat 7 in my case).
That's all. Just build the project now and everything will be fine."

This solution worked for me.