# How to get rid of "javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext cannot be resolved to a type" in jsp page with Eclipse?

Tags: jsp, eclipse-juno, m2e, m2e-wtp

I have this weird error in a .jsp page in eclipse:

```
javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext cannot be resolved to a type
```

My project is a **maven project** imported into **"as an existing maven project"** into **juno** with **m2e** and **m2e-wtp** plugins installed.

Is this a bug of the m2e plugins ? If yes, what's a possible workaround to get rid of this error (and the red mark in the workspace explorer) ?

Otherwise, do I need to "tell" to maven that my project contains jsp pages ? And hopefully, the m2e plugin will add the right library to the classpath. If yes, how ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After upgrading to Kepler and updating all plugins, the issue disapeared. It was probably a bug.

Answer (score 8):

The solution that worked for me, is given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15782094/453673). Go to project properties > Targeted runtimes > Select the checkbox for a runtime (Apache Tomcat 7 in my case).
That's all. Just build the project now and everything will be fine.

Comment: Had to make sure that "only" Tomcat 7 is selected. I had Tomcat 6 too selected along with Tomcat 7 and it kept on giving this error.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked in my case.. Thanks