# Resource not found in while making first example in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am making simple example hello but I am getting error resource not found.
**The requested resource (/Spring3MVC/hello) is not available.**

this are my file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>Spring3MVC</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">


    <context:component-scan
        base-package="net.viralpatel.spring3.controller" />
        <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>


package net.viralpatel.spring3.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        String message = "Hello World, Spring 3.0!";
        System.out.println(message);
        return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);
    }

}
```

hello.jsp
    
    
        Spring 3.0 MVC Series: Hello World - ViralPatel.net
    
    
        ${message}

index.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring 3.0 MVC Series: Index - ViralPatel.net</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="hello">Say Hello</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The dispatcher servlet is mapped to an invalid url, `*` is not a valid servlet mapping, change the mapping to:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In general the `url-pattern` must start or end with a `*` (*.jsp, /resources/* or /*)or be a fixed string like `/hello`.

Also you will need to change the href attribute to prefix the context root:

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/hello">Say Hello</a>
```

Comment: i am getting error..Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - End tag of element <a>
 - javax.servlet.ServletException cannot be resolved to a 
  type
 - Start tag of element <a>

Comment: when i add this <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/hello">Say Hello</a>

Comment: still i am getting resouce not found..:(

Comment: I was wrong the `<a/>` should have the context root. I think you have not included the runtime, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15781902/javax-servlet-servletexception-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type-in-spring-web-app

Comment: NO ..sir can you please give example on drop box so that I am able to use